# ssh on windows - Corrupted MAC on input

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssl

I've installed OpenSSH on Windows.

I can successfully connect to my remote server via ssh with Putty from this Windows machine.

But when opening a PowerShell, and trying

```
ssh my_user@1.2.3.4
```

I've got the error:

```
debug3: send packet: type 5                                                                    
Corrupted MAC on input.                                                                        
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 1.2.3.4 port 22: message authentication code incorrect
```

When looking on my remote server in the secure logs, I've got:

```
Dec  7 03:20:22 allo-01 sshd[10102]: Connection from 4.3.2.1 port 49869 on 1.2.3.4 port 22
Dec  7 03:20:23 allo-01 sshd[10102]: Connection reset by 4.3.2.1 port 49869 [preauth]
```

Do you know what's wrong? Why my ssh command from openssl on windows behave differently from PuTTY?

Comment: Include the pem file to auth with?

Comment: The Windows OpenSSL is based on LibreSSL vs. hosts are probably running openssh based on openssl - hence the slight algo mismatch.  Pity it fails to negotiate as it should.

Answer (score 63):

Raoul's answer to his own question is correct. I ran into the same issue and adding the correct algorithm name after the `-m` option works (in my case the option was `-m hmac-sha2-512` to connect from PowerShell to a machine running Ubuntu 18.04).

I wasn't sure which algorithm to use, but you can list all the available ones by running:

```
ssh -Q mac
```

I selected one at random, tried it and the remote server returned saying that algorithm wasn't supported, but it handily told me which one's were so that I could amend my command. Using this command I could then ssh into the remote machine:

```
ssh -m hmac-sha2-512 <user_name>@<remote_address>
```

If you need to use `scp` too, the parameter is different:

```
scp -o MACs=hmac-sha2-512 <and the rest of your scp command>
```

Comment: I'm wondering why this is needed when connecting to a CentOS 7 host but it isn't needed on an Ubuntu 20.04 - both with same MACs configuration in sshd_config.

Comment: As @jake mentioned, ssh my_user@1.2.3.4 -m hmac-sha2-512 This works

Comment: If you try to connect to the remote host using the ssh verbose (-v) param it will report back several options eg "Their offer: umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com"  I went though this sub list until one worked, saves a bit of time going through the full list.

Comment: Even i faced this same issue. Is there anything wrong with my SSH client?

Answer (score 9):

Well,

```
Corrupted MAC on input.
```

let me think about something wrong with my ethernet card.

Indeed, in ssh world, MAC means "message authentication code".

So, I resolve my issue by adding to my ssh command option -m with an accepectable algorithm by the remote.

Answer (score 9):

I tried many solutions that were available, but the below one worked.

Add "MACs hmac-sha2-512" to the SSH config file